# Customize Order confirmation email with line item properties

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I'm customizing order confirmation email but when I tried to send line item property, it shows as name and value in one line like this. *Width900*. 
I want to show *Width: 900* in *name: value* format.

How can I do this?

```
{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}
{% for p in line.properties %}
<span>{{ p }}</span><br/>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line.properties` will give you a json object. Try this

```
{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}
{% for p in line.properties %}
<span>{{ p.first }}: {{ p.last }}</span><br/>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```